# Regular expression to count number of commas in a string

Tags: regex

How can I build a regular expression that will match a string of any length containing any characters but which must contain 21 commas?

Comment: Should it contain exactly or at least 21 commas?

Answer (score 114):

```
/^([^,]*,){21}[^,]*$/
```

That is:

```
^     Start of string
(     Start of group
[^,]* Any character except comma, zero or more times
,     A comma
){21} End and repeat the group 21 times
[^,]* Any character except comma, zero or more times again
$     End of string
```

Comment: Very nice explanation.  Just make sure you put that in the comment in the code.

Comment: thanks that really good 

only thing is ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, etc is allowed 
how can i include this?

Comment: This regex will allow 21 consecutive commas - to prevent that, change both of the * to +

Comment: Also, using *+ (or ++) instead of * (or +) may be faster, if your regex engine supports it.

Comment: Also, regarding Robert's comment - see my answer below which uses (?x) to enable commenting, so both the regex and explanation can live together.

Comment: @Peter, JavaScript doesn't support possessive quantifiers. I doubt it would make a noticeable difference here anyway.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using a regex variety that supports the Possessive quantifier (e.g. Java), you can do:

```
^(?:[^,]*+,){21}[^,]*+$
```

The Possessive quantifier can be better performance than a Greedy quantifier.

Explanation:

```
(?x)    # enables comments, so this whole block can be used in a regex.
^       # start of string
(?:     # start non-capturing group
[^,]*+  # as many non-commas as possible, but none required
,       # a comma
)       # end non-capturing group
{21}    # 21 of previous entity (i.e. the group)
[^,]*+  # as many non-commas as possible, but none required
$       # end of string
```

Answer (score 8):

Exactly 21 commas:

```
^([^,]*,){21}[^,]$
```

At least 21 commas:

```
^([^,]?,){21}.*$
```

Comment: The first will match more than 21 commas (because it's not anchored) and if you anchor it the string will have to end with comma

Comment: This isn't right.  Why do you require that the string not end in a comma? The question didn't say that.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk He could fix it pretty easily with:^([^,]*,){21}([^,]*)$

Answer (score 7):

Might be faster and more understandable to iterate through the string, count the number of commas found and then compare it to 21.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?:[^,]*)(?:,[^,]*){21}$
```

Comment: You can remove the '?:' if you're not using .NET

Comment: Irrespective of regex version, you should leave the ?: unless you want to capture the group.

Answer (score 1):

if exactly 21:

```
/^[^,]*(,[^,]*){21}$/
```

if at least 21:

```
/(,[^,]*){21}/
```

However, I would suggest don't use regex for such simple task. Because it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

What language? There's probably a simpler method.

For example...

In CFML, you can just see if `ListLen(MyString)` is 22

In Java, you can compare `MyString.split(',')` to 22

etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
var valid = ((" " + input + " ").split(",").length == 22);
```

or...

```
var valid = 21 == (function(input){
    var ret = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++)
        if (input.substr(i,1) == ",")
            ret++;
    return ret
})();
```

Will perform better than...

```
var valid = (/^([^,]*,){21}[^,]*$/).test(input);
```

Answer (score -10):

```
.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,
```

Comment: This will match more than 21 commas

Comment: And it's unreadable too! There's a reason {num} syntax exists.

Comment: Agreed, it's unreadable. The {21} syntax is preferable.  But it makes the point visibly: just repeat what you want.  It also has the advantage of working in old regex environments that don't support the repeat count syntax.

Comment: It's also extremely inefficient. The first dot-star will initially consume the whole string, then backtrack just enough to let the following comma match. Then the second dot-star-comma will have nothing to match, so the first one will be forced to backtrack again, and so on.  This is a recipe for catastrophic backtracking.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html