# How to make this regex allow spaces c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a phone number field with the following regex:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{10,10}$")]
```

This checks input is exactly 10 numeric characters, how should I change this regex to allow spaces to make all the following examples validate

```
1234567890
12 34567890
123 456 7890
```

cheers!

Comment: Are you sure that's the right regex? That looks more like an email validator

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works:

```
^(?:\s*\d\s*){10,10}$
```

Explanation:

```
^ - start line
(?: - start noncapturing group
\s* - any spaces
\d - a digit
\s* - any spaces
) - end noncapturing group
{10,10} - repeat exactly 10 times
$ - end line
```

This way of constructing this regex is also fairly extensible in case you will have to ignore any other characters.

Comment: Btw, `\s` will match any whitespace, not just a space character.  OP might want to match any whitespace, but he did say "spaces".

Comment: @Michael Graczyk - good point; `\s` will indeed match various sorts of spaces (not sure if all, like zero-width space and other fancy spaces). If only some of them are allowed, like only the ` ` character you get by pressing spaceber, might list them like `[ ]*` or ` *` instead of `\s*`

Comment: Thanks Eugene, nice one on the explanation too

Comment: This solution counts the spaces as part of the 10 characters. Counting only the numbers is considerably harder and messier with a pure regex approach.

Comment: @Dominic Cronin - in fact, it counts groups `(?:)` of `\s*\d\s*`. With slight modification it could count any other groups. Currently, one group contains exactly one digit, which gives 10 groups of 1 digit each and an unknown number of whitespace of unknown type.

Comment: Indeed - so as I said, instead of coming up with a total of 10 digits, optionally interspersed with spaces, it matches 10 of either digit or space. Doing that is simply a matter of adding a space to the character class in the original regex, which isn't exactly difficult. However, the problem as stated is much more difficult, and I would probably not solve it with a pure regex solution.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev - I've just re-read your solution, and I'm wrong. Your group will indeed match a single digit and any surrounding whitespace, and this group must occur exactly 10 times. Assuming that spaces are allowed both before and after the phone number, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple regex

<s>`var matches = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"([\s\d]{10})");`</s>

**EDIT**

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"^((?:\s*\d){10})$");
```

explain:

```
   ^             the beginning of the string

  (?: ){10}      group, but do not capture (10 times):

  \s*            whitespace (0 or more times, matching the most amount possible)

  \d             digits (0-9)

  $              before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: Nah, `[\s\d]{10}` would not work - it takes 10 characters, some of them spaces and some of them digits.

Comment: @Ria You didn't test your code well enough. `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(new string(' ', 10), @"([\s\d]{10})").Success);` definitely prints `true`.

Comment: Still wrong: `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(new string('0', 11), @"((?:\s*\d){10})").Success);` prints `true`.  You need to check for the beginning and end of the string. See Eugene's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
^([\s]*\d){10}\s*$
```

I cheated :)  I just modified this regex here:

[Regular expression to count number of commas in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863125/regular-expression-to-count-number-of-in-string)

I tested.  It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your problem, you might consider using a Match Evaluator delegate, as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx

That would make short work of the issue of counting digits and/or spaces

Answer (score 0):

Something like this i think `^\d{2}\s?\d\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4}$`

There are variants : 10 digits or 2 digits space 8 digits or 3 digits space 3 digits space 4 digits.

But if you want only this 3 variants use something like this

```
^(?:\d{10})|(?:\d{2}\s\d{8})|(?:\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{4})$
```