# Need IP Address mask and DNS host name regular expressions?

Tags: regex, dns

I need to allow an IP/DNS name from a text box. I am looking for a IP regular expression which work for IP.

Now I am using one regular expression:

```
/\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/
```

which was working for 0-255 range. But allowing invalid IP such as : 121.21.05.234.01 which has 5 parts.

I need a regular expression which will work in all scenario's like below:

```
10.2.22.1        - true
123.123.123.123  - true
123.123.023.12   - true
12.23.12.0       - true
121.21.05.234.01 - false
```

Please provide me DNS expression also.

Comment: The `\b` in your pattern match on word-boundaries, which are the (effectively) empty spaces between `a-zA-Z0-9_` and anything not those characters. The dot for the 5th octet qualifies as "anything not those", which is why your pattern still matches. See sp00m's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your regex with `^` and `$`, which will make it match the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to specify an occurrence count?
You may achieve this with curly brackets.
An exemple [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863125/regular-expression-to-count-number-of-in-string).

In your case, it would lead to:

```
/\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\b/
```

(I added a `\` to escape the dot, too)