# Regex to delete lines containing exact number of semicolons, Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Example:

```
a ; user ; name ; pass ; 123 ;
b ; login ; name ; password ; def;
c ; 
d ;
e ; email ; s@d.com ; pass ; 789 ;
```

lines 1,2,5 have 5 semicolons and lines 3,4 have 1 semicolon I want line 3 and 4 deleted.

result:

```
a ; user ; name ; pass ; 123 ;
b ; login ; name ; password ; def;
e ; email ; s@d.com ; pass ; 789 ;
```

Comment: Have you tried putting regex together yet? When I try to work out a regex solution, I always pop it into https://regex101.com/ until I figure it out

Comment: Very similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863125/regular-expression-to-count-number-of-commas-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for deletion:

```
^[^;]*; *$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH8pA3/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following pattern in the regex matching the line to be replaced:

```
^[^;]*;[^;]*$
```

`[^;]` matches any character except the semi-colon.

The characters `^` and `$` at the beginning and the end mark the start and the end of the line respectively.

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH8pA3/2)