# A string contains at least one but no more than 2 letters "n" in C# regular expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Given a string, how could I write a regular expression that matches when the string contains at least one but no more than 2 letters "n" at any position? So far, I only came up with n{1,2}

http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: And what is wrong with `n{1,2}`?

Comment: "aanaanffnnnn" Try this

Comment: And why does it need to be a regular expression? An extension method `bool ContainsMoreThanAndLessThan(this string s, char c, int minOcurrences, int maxOccurences)` is trivial and much more flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use:

```
 ^[^n]*n[^n]*n?[^n]*$
```

Where `[^n]*` stands for 0 or more NON `n`

It will match at least one `n` and at most 2 `n`

According to comment, you could use:

```
^(?:[^n]*n[^n]*){1,2}$
```

You can change `{1,2}` into `{3,5}` or anything you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works, but is there a better way to do it? The ideal solution I wish to have is that by simply changing two numbers in the regex, i would be able to change the occurrences.

Comment: What does NON stands?

Comment: @katielu: Not the letter "n".

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!(?:.*n){3}).*n.*$
```

You can add a `lookahead` for the same.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/10

or

```
^(?!(?:[^\nn]*n){3}).*n.*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/11

Comment: @AnOverflowedStack here you can change `3` to anything u want

Answer (score 0):

Why use Regex at all? This is trival to implement in an extension method that is highly mantainable and flexible.

```
public static bool ContainsMoreThanAndLessThan(this string s, char c, int maxOcurrences, int minOcurrences)
{
    Debug.Assert(maxOcurrences >= minOcurrences);
    Debug.Assert(minOcurrences > 0);
    Debug.Assert(s != null);

    if (s.Length < minOcurrences)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var ocurrences = 0;

    foreach (var ch in s)
    {
        if (ch == c)
        {
            ocurrences++;
        }

        if (ocurrences > maxOcurrences)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return ocurrences >= minOcurrences;
}
```

Comment: Because this is a practice assignment on regular expression. :(

Comment: @AnOverflowedStack :) pretty convincing argument.

Answer (score 0):

Another example Regex, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863125/regular-expression-to-count-number-of-commas-in-a-string), will give you a match on 1 or two occurrences of the character.

```
"^([^n]*n){1,2}[^n]*$"
```

Is there a reason this cannot be solved with a simple method as InBetween suggests?