# Regular expression to count number of pattern in a string

Tags: regex

I got the following regular expression from [Regular expression to count number of commas in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863125/regular-expression-to-count-number-of-commas-in-a-string).

```
/^([^,]*,){21}[^,]*$/
```

Is the top rated solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/863137/3787418) for matching 21 commas.

How can I modify that regular expression to match 21 times 'hello world' instead of a single character?

Comment: I recommend a normal search than regex for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex really isn't the tool for that, but here you go :

```
^(?:(?:[^h]|h(?!ello world))*hello world){21}(?:[^h]|h(?!ello world))*$
```

This will only work in regex flavors which support negative lookahead.

It works in the same way than the regex you've found : in a group repeated 21 times, we match "what isn't 'hello world'", followed by one occurrence of "hello world". The difficulty is in matching "what isn't 'hello world'", which I have defined as follows :

- any character that isn't `h` (`[^h]`)
- or `h` if it isn't followed by `ello world` (`h(?!ello world)`)

Of course any sane person would choose to use a plain text search on the string instead.

Comment: Since you are advising against using regular expressions for that use case, how would you remove all lines from a file which contain 21 times 'hello world' ?

Comment: @knowname under which kind of environment? node.js?

Comment: For example under a `bash` environment with `GNU Tools` : `while read line; do [ $(echo $line | grep -Eo "\bhello world\b" | wc -l) -eq 21 ] || echo $line  ; done < source > target`