# Find multiple occurences of comma within semicolon seperated list with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to check if comma occures multiple times (or not at all) within a semicolon seperated list (Names of Authors) in a reference manager. Sadly I can only use the search function with a regular expression possibly combining more than one regex with AND, OR or NOT.

My string contains entries seperated by a semicolon. The last entry of my list does not have a semicolon at the end and also there might be no semicolon at all (because it is just one entry). Correct examples:

- `Einstein, A.; Hahn, O.; Meitner, I.`
- `Einstein, A.`

What I would like to look for with the regex is if someone did enter the name of the author the wrong way (without any comma or just comma without an semicolon as seperator). False examples:

- `Albert Einstein; Otto Hahn; Lise Meitner` (No comma within semicolon)
- `Albert Einstein, Otto Hahn, Lise Meitner` (No semicolon within list)
- `Einstein, A.; Otto Hahn; Meitner, L.` (No comma within second entry)
- `Einstein, A.; Hahn, O., E.; Meitner, L.` (two comma in second entry)

I found some similar [Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863125/regular-expression-to-count-number-of-commas-in-a-string) . However I could not get the match I need to get it into one regex.

Currently i'm combining different regex

1. Look for more than one comma without any semicolon

   ```
   ^([^,]*,){2,}
   AND
   (?:;)+
   ```
2. Look for more than one semicolon before and after a semicolon (combined with OR)

   ```
   (([^,;]*,){2,}[^;]*;)+(([^,;]*,){2,})?
   ```

I still do not get all the results. Therefore I would like to test my search with one regex checking:

1. Is there a semicolon?
2. Is there a comma inbetween semicolon or after the last semicolon?
3. Is there more than one comma inbetween semicolon or after the last semicolon?

Comment: Is your *reference manager* a commercial app or you are coding inside? What's the language / environment?

Comment: The refrence manager ist [Citavi](https://citavi.com/). It has coding capabilities in C#, but not for the search (as far as I know). I would not have postet this question if I could use C# for determine the correct string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^               # Start of string
[^,;]*,[^,;]*   # Match an entry containing exactly one comma
(?:             # Start non-capturing group:
 ;              # Match ";"
 [^,;]*,[^,;]*  # Match an entry containing exactly one comma
)*              # Group can be matched any number of times
$               # End of string
```

only matches a string if all your requirements are fulfilled.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KWSAh9/2).

Note that currently, a single comma satisfies the requirements (`,;,;,` would be legal); if you don't want that, use `[^,;]+,[^,;]+` instead of `[^,;]*,[^,;]*`.

The inverse is possible, too:

```
^                # Start of string
(?!              # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 [^,;]*,[^,;]*   # Match an entry containing exactly one comma
 (?:             # Start non-capturing group:
  ;              # Match ";"
  [^,;]*,[^,;]*  # Match an entry containing exactly one comma
 )*              # Group can be matched any number of times
 $               # End of string
)                # End of lookahead
.*               # (optional: Match the entire string
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XNiQIp/1).

Comment: Thank you @Tim for the fast answer. How could I modify the regex for not matching all my requerements?

Comment: What do you mean by this? Which requirements are optional? Or did you mean that you want the regex to match the inverse of what it's currently matching, i. e. to match any string where at least one of the requirements is not met?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I mean the inverse of what is currently matched.